# Cannot delete entries in a table that have corresponding related values in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to update and delete some items as part of a restaurant admin website. The `restaurant` table has the primary key `rest_id` and is linked to the restaurant `items` table using this key.

When I try to delete an entry in restaurant for which the corresponding items in `items` has not been populated, my code works. But, when the entry in the restaurant has some records in the `items` table, the delete query does nothing, but simply refreshes the page.

I'm trying to delete all the records in both the `restaurant` as well as `items` table. That is, if a restaurant is deleted, I want its items to be deleted as well.

```
//Update.php
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","toor");
    mysqli_select_db($con, 'eatrebs');
    $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';
    $name = isset($_POST['rname']) ? $_POST['rname'] : '';
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $address = isset($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : '';
    if(isset($_POST['del']))
    {
        if ($sql = mysqli_prepare($con,"DELETE FROM restaurant where restaurant.rest_id = ?")){
            $sql -> bind_param("s",$id);
            $sql -> execute ();
            $sql -> close();
            header('refresh:1; url="index.php"');
        }
        else{
            echo"No update";
        }
    }
    else{
        if ($sql = mysqli_prepare($con,"UPDATE restaurant SET rest_name = ?,email=?, address=? WHERE rest_id = ?")){
            $sql ->bind_param("ssss", $name, $email, $address, $id);
            $sql -> execute();
            $sql -> close();
            header('refresh:1; url="index.php"');
        }
        else{
            echo "No update";
        }
    }




?>




//index.php

<html>
    <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.css">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="PopupSearch.css">
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
        <script src="PopupSearch.js"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Owner's view</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        //Connect to mysql db
        $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','toor');
        //select database
        mysqli_select_db($con,'eatrebs');
        //Select query
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM restaurant";
        //Execute query
        $records = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        ?>
        <table>
            <h1 align="left">
                Restaurant Listings
                <button class="btn">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
            </h1>
            <Hr>
            <div id="Listingsblock">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <div id="Listing_Labels">
            <th class="text-center">Restaurant Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Email</th>
            <th class="text-center">Address</th>
            </tr>
            </div>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
        <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
        {

            echo '<tr><form action="update.php" method="post">';
            echo"<input type=hidden name=id value='".$row['rest_id']."'></td>";
            echo "<td><input type = text name = \"rname\"  value = '".$row['rest_name']."'</td>";
            echo "<td><input type = text name = \"email\"  value = '".$row['email']."'</td>";
            echo "<td><input type = text name = \"address\"  value = '".$row['address']."'</td>";
            echo"<td><input type=submit value=\"Update\">";
            echo'<td><Button btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-left name=del>Delete</Button>';
            echo "</form>";

            echo '<form action="Menu/viewMenu.php" method="post">';
            echo"<input type=hidden name=iid value='".$row['rest_id']."'></td>";
            echo"<td><input type=submit value=\"View Menu\" name=viewMenu>";
            echo'</form></tr>';

        }
        $a = mysqli_num_rows($records);
        if($a==0){
            echo'<h1>No Records Available</h1>';

        }


        ?>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        <hr>
        <hr>
        </div>
        <!--Insert Records-->
        <h1 align="left">
            Create new Listing
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="openForm()">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Plus
            </button>
        </h1>
        <br>
        <!--create entry popup-->






        <div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
            <form action="create.php" class="form-container" method="post">
            <h1>Register</h1>

            <label for="rname2"><b>Restaurant Name</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Restaurant Name" name="rname2" required>

            <label for="email2"><b>Email</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter email" name="email2" required>

            <label for="address2"><b>Address</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Address" name="address2" required>

            <button type="submit" class="btn">Register</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
          </form>

        </div>
  <hr>
        <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're throwing away the response from your database query.

You should capture this and act accordingly. [`mysqli_stmt::execute()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) returns `true` when it succeeds and `false` when it fails. If it fails you should probably do something with its [`error()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). This will let you avoid the "my page just refreshes" by showing an error message to explain what's happening.

Secondly, your database is protecting you. It wants your data to be well-formed, and if you delete a record that another record references it doesn't know what it should do. The safest thing to do, and indeed the correct thing in many cases, is to refuse to delete the referenced record.

You can change this behaviour, though. When you [add your constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) you can provide an `ON DELETE` clause, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE item
  ADD CONSTRAINT restaurant_fk
  FOREIGN KEY (rest_id)
  REFERENCES restaurant(id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Here, `ON DELETE CASCADE` tells your database that it should delete `item`s when their corresponding `restaurant`s are deleted.

You'll have to drop your old constraint before you add this one. It depends how it's currently configured, but something like

```
ALTER TABLE item
  DROP FOREIGN KEY whatever_its_name_is;
```

should do the trick.

Comment: thank you very much! However, let's say I want to maintain the data integrity while still getting rid of the restaurants. What would be the best approach for doing so? Do I need to restructure my database or something?

Comment: This _does_ maintain data integrity. It removes records that would otherwise reference a missing value. Can you be more specific about what you'd want to happen in this case? It's probably a good idea to read the "add your constraint" page I linked in my answer. It lists your options. Look at the `reference_option`s.